# How can I connect iOS app with Wit.ai iOS SDK to node.js app running wit.ai?

Tags: ios, objective-c, node.js, facebook, wit.ai

Say, for example that I am trying to make an app that recommends you a random movie. You should be able to talk to the app by pressing a button. Then the app will send your speech to a backend (a node app), which will then run the logic that will then send you back a random movie title.

This is my setup:

- A simple story in Wit Console

  - User says **I want a movie**
  - Bot then calls **searchRandomMovie** function which produces **movie** context variable
  - Then bot says **How about this: "{movie}"** which uses **movie** variable
- A node.js app that is running the wit.ai library much
  like [Wit - Quick Start](https://wit.ai/docs/quickstart) and using the token for story above.

  - Note: I can run the app locally in interactive mode and it will run the custom movie function after typing **I want a movie** and return the phrase with the movie title
- iOS App running the Wit.ai SDK

  - I put the client token on the sdk
  - Was able to get the app to record my speech, send it to wit.ai and have it return something with a level of confidence but could not connect it to my custom function in the node.js app

I am trying to get the above setup to do the following:
 - Speak the **I want a movie** sentence to the iOS app, which will send voice to Wit.ai
 - Have Wit.ai read the sentence and determine that the **searchRandomMovie** function needs to be called AND delegate to the node app to run it
 - Have the node app run the **searchRandomMovie** function and return results all the way back to the iOS app
 - Have the iOS app display the **How about this: "{movie}"** string and maybe even speak back the whole sentence

**Is this possible in the way I described it above?** I am pretty sure there is something I am missing or that I am not getting. Unfortunately, it seems Wit.ai just updated their docs and do not seem to be very thorough with a scenario like this.

I am new to Wit.ai and any help with details will be helpful

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for sharing. You're right our documentation needs to be improved a lot. the /converse endpoint (Bot Engine Beta) doesn't support speech as of now. So you will have to call /converse first and then retrieve the text and do another call to /converse. Hope this helps

Comment: Hi, thanks for providing an answer. But can you provide a little more context to your answer?

If I understand correctly, from the iPhone I would have to enter text to send over to /converse, which would then return context/intents/etc. Then   based on context I could go ahead and call my function, get the data I need (movie title), and call /converse and give it the data I fetched (in proper context) so that wit.ai can then return the appropriate Bot Says message.

Does that seems like the appropriate scenario? If so, do you have any pointers on API docs to make that happen?

Thanks